# Storybook "module not found"

Tags: storybook

I've written a NextJS module that includes an NPM module via a regular `import`. The module works fine with this module.

I'm now trying to write a Storybook story for it, but I get the following error when trying to start Storybook:

```
ERROR in ./components/ImageCarousel.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'swiper/css' in 'C:\Projects\Work\voyager\components'
 @ ./components/ImageCarousel.tsx 5:0-20
 @ ./components/ImageCarousel.stories.tsx
 @ ./components sync ^\.(?:(?:^|[\\/]|(?:(?:(?!(?:^|[\\/])\.).)*?)[\\/])(?!\.)(?=.)[^\\/]*?\.stories\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx))$
 @ ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/globals.js ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addParameter.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-measure/dist/esm/preset/preview.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/storybook-addon-outline/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-a11y/dist/esm/a11yRunner.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-a11y/dist/esm/a11yHighlight.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/storybook-tailwind-dark-mode/dist/preset/preview.js-generated-other-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined
```

I've tried adding lots of different code to the `./storybook/main.js` in `webpackFinal` but none of it seems to work.

I'm not sure what else to try.

Why can't Storybook find my NPM module in the `node_modules` folder? What am I missing?